# one to many and self referencing in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two entities with following relationShip (these entities are taken for example purpose only)

```
public class Entity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

public class Doctor : Entity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string sprcialization { get; set;}
    public string Icollection<JrDoctor> childDoctors { get; set;}
}

public class JrDoctor : Entity
{
    public long? DoctorId { get; set;}
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set;}

    public long? JuniorDoctorId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("JuniorDoctorId")]
    public virtual Doctor JuniorDoctor { get; set;}
}
```

this relationship in entityframework is creating an extra column Doctor_Id in JrDoctor table. Why is it so? and how can I avoid it using data annotations.

Comment: What is key in your `Doctor` entity? Same question about `JrDoctor` entity?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ID is the Key in both tables, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is how EF works - if it sees navigation property (`Doctor` in your case), then EF understands that both entities are related to each other. Relation in database is defined by foreign keys. So EF generates foreign key with name `PropertyName_KeyColumnOfRelatedEntity`. That's why you see column `Doctor_Id` in JrDoctor table.

If you don't want default generated foreign key column, then you should tell EF what it should use instead. That is done via [data annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attributes or [fluent configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx). I prefer latter one:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JrDoctor>()
    .HasOptional(jd => jd.Doctor) 
    .WithMany(d => d.childDoctors) 
    .HasForeignKey(jd => jd.DoctorId); // here you tell which column is FK
```

Data annotations require modification of entity classes. In your case you should add attribute which tells name of FK for navigation property, just as you did for `JuniorDoctor`:

```
public class JrDoctor : Entity
{
    public long? DoctorId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set;}

    public long? JuniorDoctorId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("JuniorDoctorId")]
    public virtual Doctor JuniorDoctor { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I tried decorating the Doctor Navigation property with ForiegnKey, but ef still generated Doctor_Id column in the JrDoctor table.  I feel it is something to do with the one to many relation ship, ef might have created the additional key for maintaining the one to many relationship.  Can I use InverseProperty on top of collection property in Doctor class??

Comment: @zeroCool make sure that database was dropped and re-created with your new model: `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>())`

Comment: Berezovsky yes I deleted the data base manually before running

Comment: @zeroCool sorry, I need to go now. Verify your connection and make sure you are looking on target database. With `ForeignKey` attribute EF should not generate default FK column.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Berezocsky for your help :) InverseProperty solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

InverseProperty did the trick.

```
public class Entity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

public class Doctor : Entity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string sprcialization { get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("Doctor")]
    public string Icollection<JrDoctor> childDoctors { get; set;}
}

public class JrDoctor : Entity
{
    public long? DoctorId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set;}

    public long? JuniorDoctorId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("JuniorDoctorId")]
    public virtual Doctor JuniorDoctor { get; set;}
}
```